# Pass list <String> from apex to LWC component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have below set of codes in which I am trying to pass `List<String>` value to my lwc component. But I am not getting any value.

Apex Code:

```
    public class test2 {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<string> insightTest(string rec){
    
        -------------My  code------------------
        string columnName = 'somevalue';
        String columnValue = 'somevalue';
        List<string> predictlistTest=new List<string>();
        predictlistTest.add(columnValue);
        predictlistTest.add(columnInputVal);
        return predictlistTest;
    }
}
```

jscode

```
    import { LightningElement,track,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import insightTest from '@salesforce/apex/test2.insightTest';

export default class Test2 extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track recordData ;
    
        
    @wire(insightTest,{rec:'$recordId'})
    getprediction({predictlistTest, error  }) {
       
        if (predictlistTest) {
            
           this.recordData=predictlistTest;
           
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
}

}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <template >
   <template if:true={recordData}>
      {recordData}
   </template>
   <template if:true={error}>
     {error}
   </template>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue lies here: `getprediction({predictlistTest, error  })`

That notation is the [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which extract the specified properties from an object, i.e.

```js
const obj = { a: 'hello', b: 'salesforce', c: 'stackexchange' };
const {a, z, b} = obj;
console.log(a); // hello
console.log(b); // salesforce
console.log(z); // undefined because obj has no property "z"
```

The object returned by a wire adapter holds two properties: `data` and `error`. It has no `predictlistTest` property, that's why it will never enter in the `if (predictlistTest)` block.

You should change the wired block to:

```js
@wire(insightTest,{rec:'$recordId'})
getprediction({ data, error  }) {
    if (data) {
       console.log([...data]);
       this.recordData = data;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Since the apex method returns a list, you may want to [iterate over it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_lists).

Moreover, as Pankaj said, there is no need to use `@track` decorator here. Indeed [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reactivity_fields) states:

> If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value.

**Iterate over a list**:

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-card slds-var-p-around_small">
        <template for:each={recordData} for:item="record" if:true={recordData}>
            <p key={record}>{record}</p>
        </template>
        <span class="slds-text-color_error"  if:true={error}>
            {error}
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi RubenDG,
I tried replacing by data, still I am not getting any value.

Comment: @user105568 what if you add a `console.log()` in `if(data)` block? Is the apex method you posted exactly the one you have on your org or did you removed/modified something before posting it here? Please also go in Setup > Session Settings, deselect *Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance* than save and refresh the page with the component

Comment: In console.log(), I am not getting any value.
Yes, my apex code is same am just returning 2 string values from my apex code.

Comment: @user105568 could you please edit your question posting the whole js file as is now after the update of wired block and with the `console.log(data);`?

Comment: I am getting [object], in console.log(data);

Comment: @user105568 That's means that `recordData` is setted. Please use the html I added to the answer and let me know if you see the text.

Comment: I am getting this [object Object]

Comment: @user105568 I updated the html in the answer. Do you still see [object Object]?

Comment: Yes. Its still same  [object Object].

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of @track, as every properties is tracked automatically by salesforce now.

This is how I would call Apex class from js Code -

```js
    import insightTest from '@salesforce/apex/test2.insightTest';

    export default class testLwcWay extends LightningElement {
         console.log('================inside method ======================');

         //js method name
         methodName(){
              //apex method name
              insightTest({recId : this.recordId})
                   .then(result => {
                        console.log(result);
                        //do something with result variable
                   })
         }
    }
```

You will then need to call the method from HTML as -

```
<input type="button" onclick={methodName}>
```

for better understanding please refer this link --
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative

Comment: track is still necessary for objects and arrays, just not for normal variables. It's the nuance that matters for a statement like this.

Comment: Hi Pankaj,
Tried by way you suggested but didn't get the value.

Comment: I have updated my code. please check.